# Does there exist a PHP event observer framework

Tags: frameworks, observer-pattern, php

I'm looking to create a re-distributable PHP script and provide the ability to extend the application with plugins. The basic architecture should work just like magento.

Is there a PHP event / observer framework available ?

Comment: If it should work just like magento, shouldn't you just use magento? Also, have you checked out the SplSubject and SplObserver interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect each framework to handle those events in their unique way. I've implemented observer / events through object-level callback hooks which can be multi-purpose and higher performance than the Spl Implementation.

Comment: Is there any place where i can get any reference on the callback hooks technique you mentioned ?

Comment: I'll be releasing decent documentation with 4.2, so far they are undocumented. https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/4.2/lib/AbstractObject.php#L375 is the source. They are also used for method injection. AbstarctObject is a base object for every other object. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUNEHqYVOYs will explain the basic concept. Hope this helps.